# EF6 - DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I get this error when attempting to add anything into the table. Other tables work fine, i have figured out it happens only on table that contains triggers.

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

This is my code, but it works fine when there are no triggers:

```cs
using (var context = new DbEntities())
{
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    context.Employees.Add(record);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Might be relevant to show your trigger. Otherwise it's left to guess work

Comment: "_Exception thrown by DbContext when it was expected that SaveChanges for an entity would result in a database update but in fact no rows in the database were affected._" So for some reason the record is not added. Try to disable all triggers and see if the error persist. If you have multiple triggers, add them back one at the time until the error occurs again.

Comment: It's pretty big and not in english. `SET NOCOUNT` is `ON` (checked both, both fail). Basically i do things, and at the end just inserting the data. Works fine on the database end, EF6 has issues with understanding that data is safe on the server side.

Comment: @Michael its fine without triggers. I have found similar issues here, but no one was able to find solution.

Comment: So what you are saying is that data is saved in the database, even though EF throws the exception?

Comment: No it's not. I just mean that EF6 tries very hard to stop saving this data even though SQL Server will handle it properly.

Comment: Could it be that `@@rowcount` is returning an unexpected number of rows from the trigger - `@@rowcount` always returns the number of rows affected by the last operation. If that is the issue you could put a dummy operation to affect the correct number of rows at the end of your trigger?

Comment: @DaleK no idea how to do that. But i have found out that placing `SELECT` at the end fixes the issue. But i feel like its not very professional solution.

Comment: It sounds like you have done exactly as I suggested :) yes it does sound like a cludge, but it also sounds like EF is being over-protective if it doesn't allow you to do stuff in a trigger which affects additional records.